# Android Studio : renaming a directory or a class uses fully qualified names

Tags: java, android

Sometimes when I rename a directory or a class, the references of the corresponding classes (the classes in the directory or the class itself) are replaced by their fully qualified name instead of being imported, which is a bit ugly code wisely.

Example :
Before refactoring and renaming :

```
package com.domain.package1;

public class Class1 {
    public Class1() {
    }
}

package com.domain.package2;

import com.domain.package1;

public class Class2 {
    Class1 class1Instance;
    public Class2() {
        class1Instance = new Class1();
    }
}
```

after renaming `Class1` to `Class1New` the code becomes like this

```
package com.domain.package1;

public class Class1New {
    public Class1New() {
    }
}

package com.domain.package2;

public class Class2 {
    com.domain.package1.Class1New class1Instance;
    public Class2() {
        class1Instance = new com.domain.package1.Class1New();
    }
}
```

or after renaming `package1` to `package1new` the code becomes like this

```
package com.domain.package1new;

public class Class1 {
    public Class1() {
    }
}

package com.domain.package2;

public class Class2 {
    com.domain.package1new.Class1 class1Instance;
    public Class2() {
        class1Instance = new com.domain.package1new.Class1();
    }
}
```

I tried unchecking `Use fully qualified class names` in Settings but nothing changed.
Any suggestions?

Comment: you can check answers of  this question. It may help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package?

Comment: Actually I am using this method but I am not necessarily renaming the root package, I am trying to rename any directory or class in my project but sometimes the class names are replaced by their fully qualified names instead of being imported.